# How to save file in Downloads folder in Flutter for Android 13?

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions

In my Flutter application, I want to save it in Download folder. I am using **permission_handler** to get permission for **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** and **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**.

Permission is working fine below Android 13 but for Android 13, I am not able to get permission for storage so I am not able to save download file due to permission issue.

```
final permissionStatus = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (permissionStatus.isDenied) {
      // Here just ask for the permission for the first time
      await Permission.storage.request();

      // I noticed that sometimes popup won't show after user press deny
      // so I do the check once again but now go straight to appSettings
      if (permissionStatus.isDenied) {
        await openAppSettings();
      }
    } else if (permissionStatus.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      // Here open app settings for user to manually enable permission in case
      // where permission was permanently denied
      await openAppSettings();
    } else {
      // Do stuff that require permission here
    }
```

How can I get rid of this issue for Android 13?

Comment: If the user accepts the permission, then app doesn't save in downloads?